# Event that gets called when the control finished binding

Tags: wpf, events, data-binding

I have an ItemsControl control. In its items I show a lot of things: images, textblocks, etc.

I have a 'Search' functionality implemented on the itemscontrol - meaning that if the user enters some letters from the keyboard, the items control will be refreshed. My Search method is in code-behind and it takes less than a second. However, the time between I enter the letters and see the results is 3-4 seconds. I have a window closing command and I want to put it in the exact moment before showing the search results. If I put this command in the end of my Search method (in the code-behind), there is still a few seconds delay between closing the window and showing the items. I'm thinking that the binding is slow and that's why i need to catch the event that gets called when the binding finishes. Is there such an event in WPF?

OnPropertyChanged event gets called before the Search methods finishes, so that doesn't help me.

I also tried with the OnDataContextChanged event, but it gets called just once - when the control is initialized. I need it to also get called when the user enters letters and new binding occurs.

Comment: Have you enabled virtualization? How do you refresh the control with the filtered list?

Comment: @Pragmateek I refresh it with the OnPropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you establish a data binding between a source property and a target dependency property in WPF, this `Binding` is actually translated into a `BindingExpression` object which does the heavy lifting of updating the source and the target at the appropriate moments.

Unfortunately, `BindingExpression` does not provide events when something is updated, as you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression(v=vs.110).aspx

The only way is to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` when you define your binding, get the binding expression in code behind and update the source and target manually - then you have full control and can encapsulate your common functionality in this scenario.

You can obtain the `BindingExpression` by using the `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression` static method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression(v=vs.110).aspx

If you have any further questions, please feel free to ask.

P.S.: isn't there maybe another way to do this? If you're using a source collection that you bind to your `ItemsControl`, couldn't you perform the searching / filtering operations on the source collection and just let the collection binding update your `ItemsControl`?

Comment: "update the source and target manually" How can I update it manually from code-behind? It's actually a one-way binding.

Comment: If you have a look at the `BindingExpression` class (see link in answer), you'll find two methods: `UpdateSource`and `UpdateTarget`. You just have to call these at the appropriate time which is specific to your development context.

Comment: But I can't see a difference between this and what I already do. Even after I call the UpdateSource property, there is still a delay of a few seconds and I can't catch the exact moment before the binding is finished.

Comment: Why not? The binding finishes when the `UpdateSource` method returns. You can even put a `Stopwatch` around this call.

Comment: BindingExpression be = SearchItemsControl.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty); returns null. What am I doing wrong? SearchItemsControl is the name of the ItemsControl, and ItemsSource is the property I set the binding.

Comment: I don't know, could you provide some code? If `SearchItemsControl.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty)` returns null, then the binding is not (yet) in place. Did you execute this statement before the corresponding XAML was parsed?